# Web service deployment: Service does not work out of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, deployment, wsdl, http-status-code-404, tomcat7

I have developed a simple WSDL web service. It is working with no problems in Eclipse. But when I deploy it in Tomcat , which is the same Tomcat server I use in Eclipse, I am getting following error:

```
type Exception report

message (404)Not Found

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: (404)Not Found
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

(404)Not Found
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    gyte.kiosk.WriteAnnouncementSoapBindingStub.vriteAnnouncement(WriteAnnouncementSoapBindingStub.java:108)
    gyte.kiosk.WriteAnnouncementProxy.vriteAnnouncement(WriteAnnouncementProxy.java:55)
    org.apache.jsp.proxy.Result_jsp._jspService(Result_jsp.java:106)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.
```

I have put classes with in the Web-Inf folder. What else shoul I do to fix this problem?

Apache Tomcat 7.0.34
Windows 8 x64

Here is the Tomcat log:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/gytekioskduyuru] threw exception [(404)Not Found] with root cause
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (404)Not Found
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {}:return code:  404
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 - Error report&lt;/title&gt;&lt;style&gt;&lt;!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--&gt;&lt;/style&gt; &lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;h1&gt;HTTP Status 404 - /GyteKiosk/services/WriteAnnouncement&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;HR size=&quot;1&quot; noshade=&quot;noshade&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;type&lt;/b&gt; Status report&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;message&lt;/b&gt; &lt;u&gt;/GyteKiosk/services/WriteAnnouncement&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;description&lt;/b&gt; &lt;u&gt;The requested resource is not available.&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;HR size=&quot;1&quot; noshade=&quot;noshade&quot;&gt;&lt;h3&gt;Apache Tomcat/7.0.34&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:404

(404)Not Found
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at gyte.kiosk.WriteAnnouncementSoapBindingStub.vriteAnnouncement(WriteAnnouncementSoapBindingStub.java:108)
    at gyte.kiosk.WriteAnnouncementProxy.vriteAnnouncement(WriteAnnouncementProxy.java:55)
    at org.apache.jsp.proxy.Result_jsp._jspService(Result_jsp.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Paste whats in the Tomcat logs :)

Comment: @cowls I have added tomcat logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Right click on project -> Export -> WAR File

[image]